# How can I get the tax code of an order from a Magento's API

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento's API (V2) to retreive orders so I can import them into our financial system. One requirement is that I include the Magento tax code for each order.

To be specific I'm looking for the value of the "code" column within the sales_order_tax table for a given order.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Was the information not a part of your call to http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order#sales_order.info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this information is not available via their API. Neither http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order#sales_order.info or http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/sales_order#sales_order.list offer this and from perusing through the WSDL, it doesn't look like it's available anywhere.

As a result, I'm having to go through the DB directly.